# How to know selected HTML when using Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I'm developing a web page and I'm using Firebug to inspect it. I know how to find the related CSS and modify it accordingly. But how can I find physically the HTML to modify?

Comment: What do you mean by 'physically'? If you mean how to change the HTML in Firebug permanently, then please see ['How can I save changes I made inside the HTML panel back to my source file?'](http://getfirebug.com/faq#How_can_I_save_changes_I_made_inside_the_HTML_panel_back_to_my_source_file) in the FAQ to Firebug.

Comment: I'm asking how to find the file that needs to be modified...

Comment: Then please see ['Where is the source shown inside the HTML panel located?'](http://getfirebug.com/faq#Where_is_the_source_shown_inside_the_HTML_panel_located).

Answer (score 0):

The *HTML* panel within Firebug shows a live view of the HTML structure of your page. That means the displayed elements may come from a server request or they are generated via JavaScript.
If the HTML comes from a network request, it is normally dynamically generated on the server through a server-side language and not a static file only containing HTML.

1. **Check whether the HTML comes from a server request**

   1. Switch to the *Net* panel and reload the page via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to circumvent the browser cache.
   2. Click into the search field at the top right of Firebug and ensure *Response Bodies* is checked within the search options.
   3. Type in the contents of your element. => In case there is a match, the *Net* panel will expand the related request and mark the match within the response.
   4. Hover the request (preceded by 'GET' or 'POST') => You will see the URL of the request. That URL is where the HTML comes from.
2. **Check whether the HTML is dynamically generated via JavaScript**

   1. Enable the *Script* panel
   2. Switch to the *HTML* panel
   3. Right-click an ancestor of the element and choose *Break On Child Addition or Removal* (this will stop the JavaScript execution once the element is created)
   4. Do the action that causes the element to be added to the page. => The script execution will be halted at the line where the element is added.